# Bluetooth auto connect to headset

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Android 2.2 on my samsung. One problem that I hate is that when I turn on bluetooth then turn on my handsfree headset it doesn't auto connect. It's paired and works, but each time I have to go to system settings, then wireless, then bluetooth and finally select the headset to connect.

This is very annoying. My old Nokia N95 would auto connect, why can't Android.

Is there a setting I am missing for auto connect?

Answer (score 0):

Android surely can do that as well. Unfortunately, you've been a bit vague on the devices used: Samsung is a manufacturer having brought out plenty of smartphones, and there are also plenty of Bluetooth headsets; maybe there's something with that specific combination.

Nevertheless, there are some generic solutions available on the Playstore, like [Bluetooth Auto Connect](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bluetooth-auto-connect/org.myklos.btautoconnect): *It automatically tries to connect to your Bluetooth devices when Bluetooth has been turned on or when your device screen goes on.* Unfortunately, this only works with Android 3.0+, so it's not really a solution for you – but a [search for "bluetooth auto connect"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=bluetooth%20auto%20connect) will give you additional alternatives, one of those hopefully works with your Android version:

There's e.g. [Shake To Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathokkil.stc) working with Android 2.2+, which at least should save you from the "long walk through the menus".

Note however that I didn't try any of those solutions, so no guarantees :)